# I need to print variable in result set

Tags: mysql

I need to be able to convert an input variable to a datetime or timestamp - then send it back to the results set as part of the select statement. I have prepared the code below which of course does not work - it sends me **1970-01-01** regardless of what the unix time is. These are the pieces I am trying to send to the result set:

FROM_UNIXTIME(startDate,"%Y-%m-%d") AS startingDate, 
    FROM_UNIXTIME(endDate,"%Y-%m-%d") AS endingDate

```
CREATE PROCEDURE reportFreeCoolingTracker (
        IN fromDate varchar (50),
        IN toDate varchar (50),
        IN timeZone varchar (50))

    BEGIN
            DECLARE startDate varchar (50);
            DECLARE endDate varchar (50);


             SET startDate = FROM_UNIXTIME(fromDate/1000);
             SET endDate = FROM_UNIXTIME(toDate/1000);

 SELECT g.groupId,
    g.name AS groupName,
    g1.parentId AS parentId1, 
    g1.name AS group1Name,
    g2.parentId AS parentId2, 
    g2.name AS group2Name,
    g3.parentId AS parentId3,
    g3.name AS group3Name,
    l.logId,l.name AS logName,
    l.ordering AS logOrder,
    a.activityId AS activityId,
    a.ordering AS activityOrder,
    a.name AS activityName,
    l1.recordId,
    l1.started, l1.completed,
    l1.userId,l1.note,
    u.name,
    TO_SECONDS(t2.completed) - TO_SECONDS(l1.completed) AS timeInSeconds,
    substr(l.details, instr(l.details , ':' ) +1)AS charge,l.details,
    i.itemId,
    i.name AS itemName,
    i.itemType,
    i.details,l1.item31985,l1.item31987,
    (l1.item31985 - l1.item31987) AS kwDifference,
    ((l1.item31985 - l1.item31987) *  (substr(l.details, instr(l.details , ':' ) +1))) AS cost,
    (((l1.item31985 - l1.item31987) *  (substr(l.details, instr(l.details , ':' ) +1)))
    *(time_to_sec(timediff(t2.completed, l1.completed)) / 3600)) AS costT,
      time_to_sec(timediff(t2.completed, l1.completed)) / 3600 AS coolingHours,
      time_to_sec(timediff(endDate, startDate)) / 3600 AS totalTimeRange,
    FROM_UNIXTIME(startDate,"%Y-%m-%d") AS startingDate, 
    FROM_UNIXTIME(endDate,"%Y-%m-%d") AS endingDate

  FROM logs l 
      INNER JOIN groups g ON g.groupId = l.groupId
      LEFT JOIN groups g1 ON g.parentId = g1.groupId
      LEFT JOIN groups g2 ON g1.parentId = g2.groupId
      LEFT JOIN groups g3 ON g2.parentId = g3.groupId                
      INNER JOIN activities a ON l.logId = a.logId 
      INNER JOIN log1644 l1 ON a.activityId = l1.activityId 
      INNER JOIN log1644 t2 ON t2.recordId = l1.recordid + 1
      INNER JOIN items i ON l.logId = i.logId AND i.name LIKE '## KW%'
      INNER JOIN users u ON l1.userId = u.userId AND i.name LIKE '## KW%'
     WHERE i.itemID = "31985"  AND  l1.activityId = 1257
      AND l1.started
        BETWEEN startDate
            AND endDate
     ORDER BY l1.started;
    END //

DELIMITER ;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to remove

```
SET startDate = FROM_UNIXTIME(fromDate/1000);
SET endDate = FROM_UNIXTIME(toDate/1000);
```

because unix timestamp works with milliseconds and use in your SELECT as

```
FROM_UNIXTIME(fromDate,"%Y-%m-%d") AS startingDate, 
FROM_UNIXTIME(toDate,"%Y-%m-%d") AS endingDate
```

Answer (score 0):

This actually does work - in fact the original query worked - I was adding it to the wrong database.

(CONVERT_TZ( (FROM_UNIXTIME(fromDate/1000)),'UTC', timeZone) )AS startingDate, 
    (CONVERT_TZ( (FROM_UNIXTIME(toDate/1000)),'UTC', timeZone) ) AS endingDate,